# Duplicate Detection In CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

In my organization, I have a sales department. The users in the sales department have given leads. Daily They call to the different leads. Now I want that two Sales Persons are not calling the same lead. So how to prevent this situation in the CRM. Moreover we are giving the random leads to all the Sales Persons. There is a possibility that two or more sales persons have same leads.

The Privileges given to the Sales Persons are:

1. They are not able to see the leads of each other.
2. They are not able to see the accounts of each other.
3. They are not able to see the contacts of each other.

Now I want that two or more Sales Persons are not having the same leads so they are not calling the same person. So how to prevent this situation in the CRM?

Comment: Are they in the same business unit?

Comment: Additionally having the same security role doesn't mean users share records, depends on the permissions granted by the role and business unit.

Comment: There are two very separate issues here I think - security roles and duplicate detection. This seems to broad to me as it is, suggest you do some reading around both and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Duplicate detection is the issue here.

Comment: Above In the comment, I write the conditions that are applied on the 2 SP.This is not the problem.

Comment: @JamesWood Yes they are in the same business unit

Comment: @glosrob I think u are not able to understand my question properly

Comment: Read my question again and then answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I have found the answer of the above question.

I have increased the privileges given to the sales persons. I have given access to see all the records of all the sales persons.

But In the Front End, I hide the system views like "All Leads", "Active Accounts", "Active Contacts" etc. and made custom views for the sales persons. Edit the filters of each view.

Because These are the views which able the sales persons to see all the records. So I hide these views from the sales persons and make custom views.

By this the two or more sales persons are not having the same leads.So they are not calling the same leads.

I will explain you how it helps: Suppose One sales person import the leads and after some time the other sales person also import some leads and if some leads are same, then the CRM will not import the duplicate leads and import the other leads which are not duplicate of the other.Moreover the sales person can see their leads which are not imported in their system by going in the Workplace and then to Imports.

Also I have made the custom Duplicate Detection Rules according to my requirement. These rules will check that the leads are not duplicate of each other according to my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate detection is limited to the records for which you are granted access. See Point 4 in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/04/29/duplicate-detection-security-model.aspx

> All users with Read privilege on the base and duplicate records and Read privilege on System Job entity can view the duplicates. **Every user will view the duplicates according to his access level on that entity.** For example, if Tim has Basic read access on Accounts entity and Jack has Global read access, then for a duplicate detection job ran by Tim for all the account records in the system, Tim will see the duplicate account records that he owns but Jack will see duplicate account records, created by all users in the organization and detected in that run.

So you have to either run a duplicated detection with administrative rights peridically or you have to grant more rights.

The reason for this is pretty simple: how would you show a user that there is a possible duplicate record when he is not allowed to view it. So it will be handled like the records don't exist.

Comment: Ok we are not able to show him the duplicate record But atleast we can intimate them that this lead is already existing in the system or it is a duplicate of the other lead when they are importing the leads in the CRM

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to increase the security privileges of each user, so they can see each others records. Or have an admin account for importing records.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not possible for me to give access of Admin account to the sales persons.

Comment: I didn't mean granting System Administrator rights, but creating an 'admin' account which has permissions to see all the required records, that 'admin' account is then used for imports.

Comment: To be honest this sounds like you have 2 contrary requirements, 1 requires records split by permissions, another requires visibility of all records. Sounds like you should resolve that contradiction